# Pandas DF. For each row, return the column name of the True value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with multiple rows, 5k+ and approximately 10 columns True/False. In each of the rows, only one of the column's entries will be True and the remaining 9 false.

```
# Import library
import pandas as pd

# Create dictionary and convert to pd DF
test = {"col1":[True, False, True, True, False],
        "col2":[False, True, False, False, True]}

test = pd.DataFrame(test)

# Show case a dataframe
print(test)
```

The dataframe should look like

```
    col1    col2
0   True    False
1   False   True
2   True    False
3   True    False
4   False   True|
```

I am hoping to return an array with the following values:

```
output_array = ['col1','col2','col1','col1','col2']
```

I'm stuck and I know I should probably use some sort of apply method and index the 10 columns, but I am not sure on the best way to screen the subset of elements of a row for True and return the column. Any help much appreciated and thank you!

Comment: `test.dot(test.columns)` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60472541/6075699

Comment: @DishinHGoyani interesting, i tried it and it works, but why does it work? what does it mean to take the dot product with the `columns`?

Comment: @tdy I guess it is doing inner product of two vectors like for first row it would be `np.array([1,0]) @ np.array(["col1","col2"], dtype="O")`

Comment: but If there is multiple `True` values then it will give like "col1col2"

Answer (score 2):

```py
true_col_name = test.idxmax(axis=1)
```

will give you a Series of which column name has the True value, assuming that there is in fact exactly one True value per row.

```py
In [6]: test.idxmax(axis=1)
Out[6]: 
0    col1
1    col2
2    col1
3    col1
4    col2
dtype: object
```

Comment: note that it will work even if there are multiple `True` values. the tie breaker will just go to the leftmost `True`.

Comment: how can I get all the columns (multiple some times) with True values?