# How to convert binary columns with multiple occurrences into categorical data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example data set

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| bar | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| baz | 1 | 1 | 0 |

How could extract the column names of each 1 occurrence in a row and put that into another column E so that I get the following table:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo | 0 | 1 | 1 | C, D |
| bar | 0 | 0 | 1 | D |
| baz | 1 | 1 | 0 | B, C |

Note that there can be more than two 1s per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.dot`.

```py
df['E'] = df[['B', 'C', 'D']].dot(df.columns[1:] + ', ').str.rstrip(', ')
df

     A  B  C  D     E
0  foo  0  1  1  C, D
1  bar  0  0  1     D
2  baz  1  1  0  B, C
```

Inspired by jezrael's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60472196/get-column-name-based-on-condition-in-pandas).

Another way is that you can convert each row to boolean and use it as a selection mask to filter the column names.

```py
cols = pd.Index(['B', 'C', 'D'])

df['E'] = df[cols].astype('bool').apply(lambda row: ", ".join(cols[row]), axis=1)
df

     A  B  C  D     E
0  foo  0  1  1  C, D
1  bar  0  0  1     D
2  baz  1  1  0  B, C
```

Comment: This answer is neat and can be applied also if there are other columns in between A and B. Marking as accepted. Could you also please explain what the dot does in this case?

Comment: The dot product does matrix multiplication. Based on my understanding, `df.dot` use `np.dot`, which use the Python native implementation of `dot`. In this case, dot product between an integer and column index is like how multiplying string and integer in python works (eg: `'A'*3 + 'B'*2` returns `'AAABB'`). It only works for string in `pd.Index` type, but not list and numpy array. I am not sure why.